# How to open Colorbox jquery plugin modal window from asp.net code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, colorbox, code-behind

I have an asp.net `listview` control with a `asp:button` in its `itemtemplate`. I want to open `Colorbox` when it is clicked and certain conditions satisfied (that is why I have trouble with calling onclientclick) and the Colorbox will show an iframe. 
I tried many diffrent ways and googled alot but none of the answers were useful to me because all of them were suggesting `onclientclick` event instead on onclick.

I'm using a code like below to open an href link in Colorbox modal dialog:

```
    <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $(".ajax").colorbox();
                    $(".iframe").colorbox({ iframe: true, 
width: "50%", height: "500px" });
                });
            </script>
```

But I can't make it work from code-behind inside a `itemcommand` event of an asp.net listview.

Can you please suggest a solution?

Comment: Also please note that the url which will be passed to color box is dynamic and generated in code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I came into finally:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnViewDetails" runat="server" Text="Details" OnClientClick="
                OpenCBox();" />
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function OpenCBox() {
                        $.colorbox({ href: '<%# Eval("EditLink") %>', iframe: true, width: "50%", height: "500px", 
                        transition: "elastic", onClosed: function () { parent.location.reload(true); } });    
                        return true;                   
                    }
                </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a hidden field on the page and set it in code-behind, then check that on `$(document).ready()`.

For example:

Page

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".ajax").colorbox();
        $(".iframe").colorbox({ iframe: true, width: "50%", height: "500px" });
        if ($('.showColorbox').val()) {
            // show the colorbox
        }
    });
</script>
```

Code-behind:

```
// in click event code
showColorbox.Value = true;
```